# Generic LensLike like mapped and traverse

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Suppose I wanted to create an "optic" for the contents of `MaybeT m a`:

`maybeTContents = _Wrapped .`***`something`***`. _Just`

Is there such a ***`something`***?

`maybeTContents` would for example be a `Traversal` when `m` is `[]`,
 but only a `Setter` when `m` is `(->) Int`.

Example usage:

```
> MaybeT [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2] ^.. maybeTContents
[1, 2]
> runMaybeT (MaybeT (Just . ('e':)) & maybeTContents %~ ('H':)) "llo"
Just "Hello"
```

Comment: @haoformayor regarding the title editing - `MaybeT` is just one example use of what I'm looking for which. hopefully the new title better explains what I'm looking for

Comment: See also https://github.com/ekmett/lens/wiki/Varying-lens-properties-by-instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to make your own class that gives the right optic for the type your using:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes             #-}

class Ocular f t where
  optic :: LensLike f (t a) (t b) a b

instance Settable f => Ocular f ((->) a) where
  optic = mapped

instance Functor f => Ocular f Identity where
  optic = _Wrapped

instance Applicative f => Ocular f [] where
  optic = traversed

instance Applicative f => Ocular f Maybe where
  optic = _Just
```

This will give a setter for `(->) s` and a traversal for `[]` etc.

```
> let maybeTContents = _Wrapped . optic . _Just
> MaybeT [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2] ^.. maybeTContents
[1,2]
> runMaybeT (MaybeT (Just . ('e':)) & maybeTContents %~ ('H':)) "llo"
Just "Hello"
```

You can also write an instance for `MaybeT` and `ReaderT`:

```
instance (Applicative f, Ocular f m) => Ocular f (MaybeT m) where
  optic = _Wrapped . optic . _Just


instance (Ocular f m, Settable f) => Ocular f (ReaderT r m) where
  optic = _Wrapped . mapped . optic

> MaybeT [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2] ^.. optic
[1,2]
> runReaderT (ReaderT (\r -> [r,r+1]) & optic *~ 2) 1
[2,4]
```

Note that the `Identity` case is only a `Lens`, not an `Iso`. For that you need to include the `Profuctor` in the `Ocular` class. You can also write a version that allows indexed lens and traversals this way.

Comment: A better version of this is to use a class associated type for the constraint, w/ a member that proves your optic is at least some minimal level of optic. Hard to do in a 400 character comment where I can't format code, but `class HasFoo e where { type T e :: * -> Constraint; foo' :: T e f => LensLike' f e Foo; fooIsALens :: T e f :- Functor f }` Then you can define `foo :: HasFoo e => Lens' e Foo` by manipulating the constraint. In monomorphic cases you proceed as before w/ `foo'`, but now you can reasonably use `foo` parametrically w/out leaking every intermediate `f` into your signature.

Comment: @EdwardKMETT - Here's what I've got so far:
https://github.com/lamdu/lamdu/blob/master/bottlelib/Data/Traversable/Generalized.hs
almost like you described but with `Functor f` in the lens' constraints instead of `fooIsALens`

Comment: @EdwardKMETT I had a go at it, is this what you mean? http://lpaste.net/168558 Can't you use type synonyms to get a similar effect (i.e. `SetFoo = HasFoo Identity`)?

Comment: You can use a Traversal at many different choices of f. If you use the version where that f leaks into the surrounding type signature and call, oh, `confusing something`, where the combinator `something` would pick `f = Something`, then all of a sudden you need `HasFoo (Curried (Yoneda Something) (Yoneda Something))` in the environment. And when you pick only one `f` you have to pay full price for it, even if you only needed something simpler. e.g. We don't always want to pay for a layer of `cloneLens` to go through Store, even though it doesn't change the answer for a lens.

Answer (score 8):

Yes! The first thing to note is that `something` must have type `Setter` (and, without loss of generality, `Setter'`). As for what type let's use holes.

```
maybeTContents :: Setter' (MaybeT m a) a
maybeTContents =
  _Wrapped . _ . _Just
```

GHC tells us it wants type `Settable f => (Maybe a -> f (Maybe a)) -> (m (Maybe a) -> f (m (Maybe a))` for the hole.

With a trip to Hackage we recognize this type as `Setter' (m (Maybe a)) (Maybe a)`. So, fixing `u ~ Maybe a`, we can rephrase the question more generally: does a setter exist that unifies with both `Setter' [u] u` exist and `Setter' (Reader u) u`?

But, as both `[]` and `Reader` have functor instances we can turn to an *absolute classic* of a setter `mapped`, [the setter heard around the world](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/wiki/Derivation). `mapped` has type `mapped :: Functor f => Setter (f a) (f b) a b` – it turns out when you have a functor instance available that `mapped = sets fmap` is the value that obeys all the setter laws.

We can see this in action here:

```
  % stack ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Ok, modules loaded: none.
λ> import Control.Lens
λ> import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
λ> import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
λ> MaybeT [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2, Nothing, Just 3] & _Wrapped . mapped . _Just .~ 100
MaybeT [Just 100,Nothing,Just 100,Nothing,Just 100]
λ> data A = A
λ> data B = B
λ> :t MaybeT (ReaderT (\r -> Identity (Just A)))
MaybeT (ReaderT (\r -> Identity (Just A)))
  :: MaybeT (ReaderT r Identity) A
λ> :t MaybeT (ReaderT (\r -> Identity (Just A))) & _Wrapped . mapped . _Just .~ B
MaybeT (ReaderT (\r -> Identity (Just A))) & _Wrapped . mapped . _Just .~ B
  :: MaybeT (ReaderT r Identity) B
```

As there was no `Show` instance for `ReaderT` the best I could do to illustrate that the setter worked was to generate two brand-spankin'-new types `A` and `B`.

This question is great I think because it gets at the heart of the motivation behind the `lens` package. Given `fmapDefault` from the `Traversable` world, you can fix the traversable to be `Identity` to write `over`. You can then write the inverse of `over`, `sets`, such that `over . sets = id` and `sets . over = id`. We are then forced to conclude that `mapped = sets fmap` is a natural setter that obeys the kind of laws we want for setters, one of the most important being that `mapped . mapped . mapped` composes with `(.)`. The rest of `lens` soon follows.

Comment: With `something = mapped`, could you do `MaybeT [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2] ^.. maybeTContents`? (Just updated my question to have this example)

Comment: @yairchu Yes. All setters are also traversals. (See: that giant UML diagram on the lens Hackage page.)

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. `:t MaybeT [Just 'a', Nothing, Just 'b'] ^.. _Wrapped . mapped . _Just` results in error `No instance for (Settable (Const (Data.Monoid.Endo [Char]))) arising from a use of ‘mapped’`...

Comment: Oh. A doy. All traversals are setters, not the other way around. I always get that confused. You want `^.. _Wrapped . traverse . _Just` I think. No such traversal will exist for `Reader`. I don't think there's any way to traverse the `a` in a Reader.

Comment: yeah I want something that will work with `^..` for `[]` but will also work with `%~` etc for `Reader`. I don't know if `Lens` already has something like it but it seems like it can be done - here's what I came up with so far - https://github.com/lamdu/lamdu/blob/master/bottlelib/Data/Traversable/Generalized.hs

Comment: Hmm. `collect` typechecks but does it do what you want? It essentially depends on the `collect` from `Distributive Identity`, right?

Comment: `collect` typechecks in the context of `_Wrapped . collect . _Just` but it doesn't seem to do what I want in all contexts..

Comment: I think that Reader intuitively won't admit a traversal here because you couldn't possibly know the value inside a Reader until you run it ... but it is difficult for me to formulate this with rigor.

Comment: yeah this "optic" couldn't be a traversal in the case of `m` being `ReaderT r`, but it should be one when `m` is `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Few examples based on previous answers:

```
> MaybeT [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2] ^.. _Wrapped . traverse . _Just
[1,2]
> runMaybeT (MaybeT (Just . ('e':)) & _Wrapped . collect . _Just %~ ('H':)) "llo"
Just "Hello"
```

I.e. for `Traversal`/`Fold` we use `traverse`, for `Setter`: `collect` (or `mapped`).

Unfortunately `Traversable` and `Distributive` don't have all instances:
`(->) r` is not `Traversable` and `Const` is not `Distributive` (and they can't be, AFAICS).

If you think about this, you see that it makes sense. `Traversal` and `Distributive` are duals, se to "go in other direction" of `traverse` we use `collect`.